# Angular Can't bind to 'dirUnless' since it isn't a known property

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to add custom unless `directive` opposite of `*ngIf`.

Here is my code:

```js
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[dirUnless]'
})
export class UnlessDirective {
    @Input() set unless(condition: boolean) {
        if (!condition) {
            this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.vcRef.clear();
        }
    }

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

Also I've added next `html`:

```html
<div *ngIf="switch"> Conditional Text IF</div>
<div *dirUnless="switch">Conditional Text UNLESS</div>
```

So obviosly only one `div` should be shown when I click `switch`.

But I have next error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'dirUnless' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

Comment: What about `*ngIf="!switch"` ? Clearly this is not an answer to your question, more a curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I've didn't declare my Directive on NgModule

Answer (score 3):

There are two options:

1) Change `@Input` name from `unless` to `dirUnless`

```
@Input() set dirUnless(condition: boolean) {
```

2) Use alias

```
@Input('dirUnless') set unless(condition: boolean) {
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/F76PrxPRf1SZFxbLoKk9?p=preview)**

Comment: The same error. I'm very new on Angular and can't understand why when I delete * and simply write

 <div dirUnless="switch">Conditional Text UNLESS</div>
The error disappears, but switch button is not work (so unless doesn't do anything)

Comment: Are you sure? Please check my plunker above

Comment: I've double checked it and I wonder why it is not working for me. Can the cause of problem be my angular version or something?

Comment: I don't think so but who knows. What's angular version you are using? Can you construct live example or github repo?

Comment: I've found my mistake. Problem was that I've didn't declare my Directive on NgModule. Thank you

Comment: @mondayguy If the solution for your question is not this answer, you shouldn't have set is as the correct one. If you found yourself the solution you can also answer yourself and mark your answer as the correct solution, so future visitors don't get confused.

Comment: @mdentinho sorry, fixed